# How to split an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP, please help me to split this array. I never do this before.

I only want to show value http://domainXXX.com **without** *string(18)* on browser.

```
array(3) {
    [7] => string(18)
    "http://domain7.com" 
    [4] => string(18)
    "http://domain4.com" 
    [3] => string(18)
    "http://domain3.com"
}
```

Comment: how did you get this array? This looks like the output from `var_dump`

Comment: use  foreach loop.

Comment: A tad confusing question, you just want to display the array values or what? If so, just use a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, exact ly output from var_dump
`var_dump($server->getLink($url));`

Comment: I just want display the array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array looks like this, a simple `foreach loop` should allow you to output the urls

```
$links=array(
    7   =>  'http://domain7.com',
    4   =>  'http://domain4.com',
    3   =>  'http://domain3.com'
);
foreach( $links as $key => $url ) {
    echo $key,' ',$url,'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Can you do an complete example for me? I just come to PHP 2days. confused!

Comment: not sure what else to put - that is pretty much the full example. A `foreach` loop is a particular type of looping construct that allows access to array members ( both to the key and the associated value )

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

don't use direct `var_dump()` to display output; you can use `foreach()` or any loop and `foreach()` has following-

```
//lets say your array name is $array
// here $key will hold 7,4,3 and $values will hold your domains
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
     echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: let me know if you have any confusoin